# TIdFTP.List takes ages

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

Following code:

```
   ftp := TIdFTP.Create(nil);
  try
    ftp.Host     := _settings.IP;
    ftp.Port     := _settings.Port;
    ftp.Username := _settings.UserName;
    ftp.Password := _settings.Password;

    ftp.ConnectTimeout := 3000;
    ftp.TransferType := ftBinary;
    _log(Format('Connecting FTP server at %s, port %d', [ftp.Host, ftp.Port]));
    ftp.Connect();
    _log('Connected');
    if _isDestroying then Exit;
    try
      ftp.ChangeDir(_settings.Path);
    except
      on E: EIdReplyRFCError do begin _logError(Format('Could not change to %s directory', [_settings.Path])); Exit; end;
    end;
    if _isDestroying then Exit;
    ftp.List();
```

ran flawlessly until an amount of files in FTP directory not exceeded 1500.

Now it takes ages to run the `ftp.List();` line. Honestly to say, I didn't see it ran up to the end.

Yes, the device's embedded FTP server isn't of great performance:
the Win7's built-in FTP client (`ftp.exe`) completes running `ls` command very fast, but when some software (either TIdFTP in my application or NetBox in Far Manager) reads files list at the same time, the `ls` command in `ftp.exe` tool runs much slower.

Is there any way to get files list as fast as `ftp.exe` it does and only then parse the list? Or may be get list items asynchronously.

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the server implementation, if another application has the same issue. Perhaps the method of connection is different. I'm fuzzy on FTP (I abandoned it years ago), but I do know there are more than one way to connect and use it. Perhaps if you switch this method, you'll find your desired behavior.

Comment: `ftp.exe` doesn't parse the list, it just displays what the server sends. If the FTP server doesn't support the MLST command, the list can be in any format the server wants. `TIdFTP` (and other parsers) have to guess what that format is. Guessing can take time. However, `TIdFTP` does not parse until the `DirectoryListing` property is accessed after `List` exits. `List` itself just downloads the raw data and stores it in the `ListResult` property, so it should be close to as fast as the server sends it. Unless the slowness is due to the `ListResult` handling, not the actual download.

Comment: Ok, Indy is good, FTP Server has problems, but what could I do now except deleting files from FTP server?

Comment: Put the files in a subdirectory structure. You don't want to show 1500+ files to the user at once anyway.